# Can ML models built using Spark MLLib be loaded and tested using Spark ML pipelines?

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I know that Spark has two libraries for Machine learning. One is `spark.ml` and another one is `spark.mllib`. I just want to know if a model that was built using `spark.mllib` pachages be used and tested(predicted) by spark program that are built with `spark.ml` and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `spark.ml` models in `spark.mllib` but not the other way around. `spark.ml` is built only around Dataframe-based API though spark.mllib and I quote the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) page

> MLlib includes both the RDD-based API and the DataFrame-based API

In a more abstracted way, you can always use model from one framework to another if you can import and set the weights.

cheers